# It is not possible ping public ip of my aci - azure container instance

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-container-instances

I've this pipeline running in azure devops:[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IYMm.png)

After run the pipeline I got the repository in azure portal and runned the instance:[run the instance of repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awFEd.png)

and after the container start run I got the ip public of the same. When I try to ping that ip I got request timed out.

Is that normal? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal. If there is no special reason, Azure will block the ICMP traffic to the service.